# Cannot convert from int to boolean?

Tags: java, casting, int, boolean

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] newArray= new int [4];
    int [] array = {4,5,6,7};
    oddEven(array);

    newArray[0] = array[0]+array[1]+array[2]+array[3];
    newArray[1] = array[0]*array[1]*array[2]*array[3];
}

public static void oddEven(int [] oddEven) {

    for (int i=0; i<oddEven.length; i++) {
        //  Cannot convert from int to boolean
        if (oddEven[i] % 2)

    }
}
```

Ignore what I'm trying to manage here. I'm only curious why it doesn't accept "if" statement in this for loop. As I stated it says "cannot convert from int to boolean".
Why do you think it says so?

Comment: Because in Java, you cannot convert an `int` to a `boolean`. The result of the `%` operator is of `int` type, whatever the divisor. `if` expects a `boolean` expression in the parentheses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That expression in side the `if` should be realizes to `boolean`  value, otherwise compilation error in java.

Try

```
       if (oddEven[i] % 2 ==0)  {
       }
```

or even (based on requirment)

```
       if (oddEven[i] % 2 !=0)  {
       }
```

See the [Language Specification# chapter 14](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)

> The Expression must have type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: But should be really `!= 0` to have the same semantics as (mis)using ints as booleans in C-like languages...

Comment: arghh I forgot that. Thank you.